# Best Practice for Combining MVC app and Web API methods

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I have created an asp.net mvc web app with VS 2013 which is working fine, but I have been asked to provide some of the same functionality to a mobile application via REST api.  The mobile app would need the same endpoints already present in my Controller, but instead of returning Views I'd need to return just 'regular' http responses.

I'm thinking that for each current ABC resource I will provide an api/ABC endpoint and have the ABC call the api/ABC.  Not sure how I can accomplish this - can I just create a new 'routing' rule?  Or should I create new api controllers and abstract out the inner functionality to a shared module?  I'd prefer to use this same VS project since we already have quite a few.

Answer (score 0):

> new api controllers and abstract out the inner functionality to a shared module?

Yes.

The MVC and API endpoints and their separate controllers<sup>1</sup> can call into shared code (which could all be in the same project).

---

<sup>1</sup> They have to be separate: they have different base types.